# a children's book- robot in family as a domestic help

Tags: story-identification, robots

A book I read as a 7-8 year old, back in '96-'98. It was a family which had a robot as a help. The baby drank a particular brand of milk that I don't remember. And the robot was programmed to feed the baby or, the robot chewed the food for the baby and put the chewed food into the baby's mouth. The baby's mother was a working woman and was always rushing to get to work.

Comment: Want to share with everyone how long ago you were 8-10 years old so we can put a time frame on this :) Any other details would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're talking about is:

> *The Type One Super Robot* by Alison Prince.

The kid's uncle names the robot *Manders* because he does everything a man does.

If not, maybe you're talking about the Richie Rich comics, where *Irona* is his robomaid's name. They've got a whole squad of robo-helpers, if I remember correectly, though.

Oh! Or the Jetsons. Family living in the future; their maid's name is Rosie. Although that's a TV show, there *were* comic-book versions of that show.

Comment: Hey, none of these. I have added more details. Maybe it rings a chord?

Answer (score 2):

I read the same (?) book a few years after you between 2005-2010.

I believe the book you're looking for is *[Eager](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1255985.Eager)*, by Helen Fox

Here's a photo of the cover.

[image: Cover of Eager, by Helen Fox]

> It's the end of the 21st century where technocrats rule and robots take care of humans’ every need. Your house watches you, knows your secrets, and talks to you. And your closest friend can be—a machine?
>
> Gavin Bell and his teenage sister Fleur come from a middle-class family. Their much-loved, old-fashioned robot, Grumps, is running down and can’t be repaired, so a scientist friend loans them EGR3, an experimental new robot to help Grumps. EGR3, known as Eager, learns from his experiences, as a child would. He feels emotions—wonder, excitement, and loss. When the ultra high-tech, eerily human BDC4 robots begin to behave suspiciously, Eager and the Bells are drawn into a great adventure that is sometimes dark and often humorous. As Eager’s extraordinary abilities are tested to the limit, he will try to find the answer to this question: What does it mean to be alive?

Comment: Can you add a few words saying how Eager matches the different parts of the original description?

Comment: I can verify, from looking at excerpts in the archive.org copy, that there is a baby named Charlotte. I haven't found a mention of chewing food for her yet, but archive.org is apparently having bandwidth troubles.

Comment: The mother is, indeed, often rushing off to work. There's an early scene where Eager tries to use the washing machine to wash the baby after they ate a sticky biscuit. Nothing that I saw about chewing food for the baby. There are covers that show the stacked-tire legs that you described in your earlier question as answer.

Comment: No particular brand of milk either, although Eager does try giving her a bottle of milk before using the "biscuit" (actually a tart that Grumps had cooked).